How to remove stop words in Power Query Editor in Power BI
I've loaded an Excel file with reviews into Power BI Desktop. I want to do Sentiment Analysis on the file. I've already turned everything in the reviews column(named Column3) to lowercase and removed punctuation marks using the Power Query Editor by inserting a new step where I have the M code for that. I next want to remove Stop Words from Column3. I inserted a new step where I created a list of stop words. But I'm having issues proceeding. How do I run Column3 through the list(named StopWords) and store the results in a new step?

See https://www.thebiccountant.com/2016/05/22/multiple-replacements-in-power-bi-and-power-query/

or https://bondarenkoivan.wordpress.com/2015/04/16/multiple-replacements-of-words-in-power-query/

Use
Table.AddColumn(colToClean, "Cleaned Column", each 
removeWords([colToClean], listRemove))

With the following custom function. Make sure you have no null values anywhere and you are treating the same type everywhere.
let
    removeWords = (inputText as text, listRemove as list) as text =>
        let
            removeWord = (text, word) => Text.Replace(text, word, ""),

            cleanedText = List.Accumulate(listRemove, inputText, removeWord) 
        in
            cleanedText
in
    removeWords

